# No option to install Visual C# 2015 in Visual Studio Professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-7-x64

I've downloaded the Visual Studio Professional 2015 RTM ISO from MSDN Subscriber downloads. When I run the installer, there is no option to install Visual C#:

[image: No C# Option!]

I see no other indications that I need to do anything to clean up from the Visual Studio 2015 RC I had previously installed and uninstalled.

How do I install Visual C#?

Comment: It is always included.  The only options you get are for very large components that you might not want to use.  Do uninstall CTP and Preview versions first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go back, and take a look at the type of installation. Under "Typical" should write "Includes C# Desktop features" or something like that. If it writes, then choose typical.

Comment: I let it finish up the custom install as pictured in my original post (without any visible C# features to enable).  It finished and rebooted, and it does appear to have installed C#.

I suppose we're expected to understand that C# will just get installed by default. That was extremely unclear from the installer UI.

Comment: Then I guess it is a feature that is installed anyway. :)
I tried once to install with custom installation (with all features selected) and Visual C# didn't seemed to be installed, but it worked with typical installation. Since then I used typical and it worked great.

Answer (score 2):

In my case at least - the Community Edition, even with all the boxes unchecked, it still installed C#. It showed me "Setup requires up to 6 GB" however - in your case it was only 600 mb.

So in the Community Edition C# is a non-optional package, and you can uncheck all the boxes. Just verify that the space required is a couple of GB - if it is, you can safely assume C# will be installed.

Answer (score 1):

But if you don't see the typical installation, you've to uninstall `Xamarin` from Control Panel and delete the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0`. After that you should install Visual Studio again.